# Calculate account balance history

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to calculate the past movements of the balance according to the transactions on the accounting account detail page as a new field on the client side and print it on the table.

```js
export default function App() {
  const transactions = [
    {
      action: "Action 4",
      total: 100
    },
    {
      action: "Action 3",
      total: -90
    },
    {
      action: "Action 2",
      total: 78
    },
    {
      action: "Action 1",
      total: -20
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <table border={1}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {transactions.map((item, index) => {
            const balance = transactions
              .slice(0, index + 1)
              .reduce((a, b) => parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b.total), 0);
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{item.action}</td>
                <td>{item.total}</td>
                <td>{balance}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the code here, I did the balance collection process, but it adds up from top to bottom. How should I arrange this process from bottom to top?

I want should be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd

1. keep the transactions originally in chronological order
2. use `useMemo` to map them into a new object with the balance too (you could also `reduce` if you like, but this feels clearer), and reverse them there.

This both allows for clearer code and less work (you do the mapping only once, instead of `reduce`ing in the render phase).

```
const transactions = [
  {
    action: "Action 1",
    total: -20,
  },
  {
    action: "Action 2",
    total: 78,
  },
  {
    action: "Action 3",
    total: -90,
  },
  {
    action: "Action 4",
    total: 100,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const transactionsWithBalance = React.useMemo(() => {
    let balance = 0;
    const withBalance = transactions.map((transaction) => {
      balance += transaction.total;
      return {
        ...transaction,
        balance,
      };
    });
    return withBalance.reverse();
  }, [transactions]);
  // Render `transactionsWithBalance` here...
}
```

Comment: If i want to do the sorting as desc, what solution would you suggest?

Comment: Remove the reverse() call to keep the original order of the transactions.

Comment: Your answer is correct both ways but my table has pagination. As you click on these pages, data comes from the database in the form of a limit of 10 short by asc. When there is more than 10 data in this section, my last action goes to the other page and I don't get what I want.

Comment: Well, you'll have to rethink how your data model works, I think - if you don't have knowledge of events on eg. the previous page, you can't compute the correct balance either. The events themselves will need to contain the balance after the transaction.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `.reduceRight` instead of `.reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight